# CakePHP - Change Controller name in URL

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a legacy application built in CakePHP 2.2.3

One part of the application has controller file which has been named SymposiumsController.php. This resulted in URL's such as:

`domain.com/symposiums`
`domain.com/symposiums/view/23`

The problem is that 'symposiums' isn't a real (English language) word; it should be 'symposia'.

I want to rename my URL's so they are like this:
`domain.com/symposia`
`domain.com/symposia/view/23`

I tried to do this by editing app/Config/Routes.php to use this:

`Router::connect('symposia/:action', array('controller' => 'symposiums'));`

However all this does is redirects `domain.com/symposia` to `domain.com/symposiums` which therefore makes no difference to what the user sees in the URL.

To put it simply I don't want 'symposiums' exposed anywhere in my URLs. I want them all to use 'symposia' in it's place.

I read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html but can't see how to do this. Does anyone have a solution? Surely I don't have to rename controllers/models and DB tables to do this?

I don't know if this makes a difference but I also have admin routing switched on so my SymposiumsController.php also has functions such as:

`admin_add()`
`admin_delete()`
`admin_edit($id)`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try setting the [name property](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$name) in the controller, I believe the Router honours that name.

Comment: @Oldskool thanks. I tried this but unforutantely it gave an error: 
Missing View
Error: The view for SymposiumsController::index() was not found.
Error: Confirm you have created the file: app/View/Symposia/index.ctp

Also tried to rename my 'Symposiums' view directory to 'Symposia' and that just then redirects back to URL's like domain.com/symposiums - which is the orignal problem

Comment: The old route may still be in the cache, try clearing that as well.

Comment: Caching is switched off in the application. I have Configure::write('Cache.disable', true); set in my config file.

Comment: `Router::connect('symposia` missing `/` in front of symposia?

Comment: @burzum Still the same result I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for this specific redirection:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:action/:id',
   array('controller' => 'symposiums', 'action' => 'view', 1)
);

:controller => Give the name new name of controller e.g. symposia
:action => Give the name new name of action  e.g. view
:id => Give the name new name of controller e.g. 23
```

But if you need to redirect more than one action then I suggest you to rename the controller.

**Note:** If you rename the controller or create new Routers then you would need to make sure in the all application modify the link to new controller name.

Source: [Cakephp Router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)